# External hive table as parquet file returns NULL when queried

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, parquet

I created a `.parquet` file by using map reduce job. Now I want to create an external table on top of this file. Here is the command:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE testparquet (
  NAME STRING, 
  AGE INT
)
STORED AS PARQUET 
LOCATION 'file location'
```

The table is created successfully but when I query the table using simple `SELECT *` , I get data as NULL for all fields. The version of hive is 0.13.

Is there anything that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

When using `external` files, you need to explicitly synchronize the metadata store that knows about the schema of your data, with the actual data itself.

Typically, you'll use the `INVALIDATE METADATA` command to force following queries to re-read the data.  You can also use `REFRESH <table-name>` if you have just one table that has been updated.